# Removing unused scripts in Avada Theme

Tags: wordpress, performance, wordpress-theming, pagespeed

Im new to avada theme but not to wordpress. I normally do custom themes. I have the latest version of Avada and right now it's loading 100+ script files. What is the best way of removing these scripts?

I've u `wp_deregister_script` on each but im just wondering why we would have to do this. Its annoying to find out which ones im actually using.

I also went into Fusion builder > Settings > and unchecked some boxes but there are still a lot of other scripts loading.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/includes/lib/assets/min/js/library/isotope.js?ver=3.0.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/includes/lib/assets/min/js/library/jquery.infinitescroll.js?ver=2.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spinplugins/fusion-core/js/min/avada-faqs.js?ver=1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/includes/lib/assets/min/js/library/modernizr.js?ver=3.3.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/includes/lib/assets/min/js/library/jquery.fitvids.js?ver=1.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var fusionVideoGeneralVars = {"status_vimeo":"1","status_yt":"1"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/includes/lib/assets/min/js/library/fusion-video-general.js?ver=1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var fusionLightboxVideoVars = {"lightbox_video_width":"1280","lightbox_video_height":"720"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/includes/lib/assets/min/js/library/jquery.ilightbox.js?ver=2.2.3'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/includes/lib/assets/min/js/library/jquery.mousewheel.js?ver=3.0.6'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var fusionLightboxVars = {"status_lightbox":"1","lightbox_gallery":"1","lightbox_skin":"metro-white","lightbox_title":"1","lightbox_arrows":"1","lightbox_slideshow_speed":"5000","lightbox_autoplay":"","lightbox_opacity":"0.9","lightbox_desc":"1","lightbox_social":"1","lightbox_deeplinking":"1","lightbox_path":"vertical","lightbox_post_images":"1","lightbox_animation_speed":"Normal"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/includes/lib/assets/min/js/general/fusion-lightbox.js?ver=1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/includes/lib/assets/min/js/library/imagesLoaded.js?ver=3.1.8'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/includes/lib/assets/min/js/library/packery.js?ver=2.0.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var avadaPortfolioVars = {"lightbox_behavior":"all","infinite_finished_msg":"<em>All items displayed.<\/em>","infinite_blog_text":"<em>Loading the next set of posts...<\/em>","content_break_point":"800"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spinplugins/fusion-core/js/min/avada-portfolio.js?ver=1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/includes/lib/assets/min/js/library/cssua.js?ver=2.1.28'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/includes/lib/assets/min/js/library/jquery.waypoints.js?ver=2.0.3'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/includes/lib/assets/min/js/general/fusion-waypoints.js?ver=1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var fusionAnimationsVars = {"disable_mobile_animate_css":"0"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spinplugins/fusion-builder/assets/js/min/general/fusion-animations.js?ver=1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spinplugins/fusion-builder/assets/js/min/library/jquery.countdown.js?ver=1.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spinplugins/fusion-builder/assets/js/min/general/fusion-countdown.js?ver=1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spinplugins/fusion-builder/assets/js/min/library/jquery.event.move.js?ver=2.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spinplugins/fusion-builder/assets/js/min/general/fusion-image-before-after.js?ver=1.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var fusionBgImageVars = {"content_break_point":"800"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spinplugins/fusion-builder/assets/js/min/general/fusion-column-bg-image.js?ver=1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var fusionEqualHeightVars = {"content_break_point":"800"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/includes/lib/assets/min/js/general/fusion-equal-heights.js?ver=1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spinplugins/fusion-builder/assets/js/min/general/fusion-column.js?ver=1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var fusionMapsVars = {"admin_ajax":"http:\/\/dev1.spinmemory.com\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/includes/lib/assets/min/js/library/jquery.fusion_maps.js?ver=2.2.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/includes/lib/assets/min/js/general/fusion-google-map.js?ver=1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spinplugins/fusion-builder/assets/js/min/general/fusion-gallery.js?ver=1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spinplugins/fusion-builder/assets/js/min/library/jquery.countTo.js?ver=1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/includes/lib/assets/min/js/library/jquery.appear.js?ver=1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var fusionCountersBox = {"counter_box_speed":"1000"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spinplugins/fusion-builder/assets/js/min/general/fusion-counters-box.js?ver=1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/includes/lib/assets/min/js/library/jquery.cycle.js?ver=3.0.3'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var fusionTestimonialVars = {"testimonials_speed":"4000"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spinplugins/fusion-builder/assets/js/min/general/fusion-testimonials.js?ver=1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spinplugins/fusion-builder/assets/js/min/general/fusion-progress.js?ver=1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/includes/lib/assets/min/js/library/jquery.easyPieChart.js?ver=2.1.7'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spinplugins/fusion-builder/assets/js/min/general/fusion-counters-circle.js?ver=1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var fusionRecentPostsVars = {"infinite_loading_text":"<em>Loading the next set of posts...<\/em>","infinite_finished_msg":"<em>All items displayed.<\/em>","slideshow_autoplay":"1","slideshow_speed":"7000","pagination_video_slide":"","status_yt":"1"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spinplugins/fusion-builder/assets/js/min/general/fusion-recent-posts.js?ver=1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/includes/lib/assets/min/js/library/jquery.fade.js?ver=1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/includes/lib/assets/min/js/library/jquery.requestAnimationFrame.js?ver=1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/includes/lib/assets/min/js/library/fusion-parallax.js?ver=1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var fusionVideoBgVars = {"status_vimeo":"1","status_yt":"1"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/includes/lib/assets/min/js/library/fusion-video-bg.js?ver=1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var fusionContainerVars = {"content_break_point":"800","container_hundred_percent_height_mobile":"0","is_sticky_header_transparent":"0"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spinplugins/fusion-builder/assets/js/min/general/fusion-container.js?ver=1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/includes/lib/assets/min/js/library/bootstrap.collapse.js?ver=3.1.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spinplugins/fusion-builder/assets/js/min/general/fusion-toggles.js?ver=1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/includes/lib/assets/min/js/library/bootstrap.transition.js?ver=3.3.6'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/includes/lib/assets/min/js/library/bootstrap.tab.js?ver=3.1.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var fusionTabVars = {"content_break_point":"800"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spinplugins/fusion-builder/assets/js/min/general/fusion-tabs.js?ver=1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spinplugins/fusion-builder/assets/js/min/general/fusion-title.js?ver=1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spinplugins/fusion-builder/assets/js/min/general/fusion-events.js?ver=1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/includes/lib/assets/min/js/library/bootstrap.modal.js?ver=3.1.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spinplugins/fusion-builder/assets/js/min/general/fusion-modal.js?ver=1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spinplugins/fusion-builder/assets/js/min/library/Chart.js?ver=2.7.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spinplugins/fusion-builder/assets/js/min/general/fusion-chart.js?ver=1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spinplugins/fusion-builder/assets/js/min/general/fusion-content-boxes.js?ver=1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/includes/lib/assets/min/js/library/vimeoPlayer.js?ver=2.2.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var fusionVideoVars = {"status_vimeo":"1"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spinplugins/fusion-builder/assets/js/min/general/fusion-video.js?ver=1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/includes/lib/assets/min/js/library/jquery.hoverintent.js?ver=1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/assets/min/js/general/avada-vertical-menu-widget.js?ver=1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/includes/lib/assets/min/js/library/bootstrap.tooltip.js?ver=3.3.5'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/includes/lib/assets/min/js/library/bootstrap.popover.js?ver=3.3.5'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/includes/lib/assets/min/js/library/jquery.carouFredSel.js?ver=6.2.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/includes/lib/assets/min/js/library/jquery.easing.js?ver=1.3'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/includes/lib/assets/min/js/library/jquery.flexslider.js?ver=2.2.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/includes/lib/assets/min/js/library/jquery.hoverflow.js?ver=1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/includes/lib/assets/min/js/library/jquery.placeholder.js?ver=2.0.7'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/includes/lib/assets/min/js/library/jquery.touchSwipe.js?ver=1.6.6'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/includes/lib/assets/min/js/general/fusion-alert.js?ver=1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var fusionCarouselVars = {"related_posts_speed":"2500","carousel_speed":"2500"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/includes/lib/assets/min/js/general/fusion-carousel.js?ver=1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var fusionFlexSliderVars = {"status_vimeo":"1","page_smoothHeight":"false","slideshow_autoplay":"1","slideshow_speed":"7000","pagination_video_slide":"","status_yt":"1","flex_smoothHeight":"false"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/includes/lib/assets/min/js/general/fusion-flexslider.js?ver=1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/includes/lib/assets/min/js/general/fusion-popover.js?ver=1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/includes/lib/assets/min/js/general/fusion-tooltip.js?ver=1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/includes/lib/assets/min/js/general/fusion-sharing-box.js?ver=1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var fusionBlogVars = {"infinite_blog_text":"<em>Loading the next set of posts...<\/em>","infinite_finished_msg":"<em>All items displayed.<\/em>","slideshow_autoplay":"1","slideshow_speed":"7000","pagination_video_slide":"","status_yt":"1","lightbox_behavior":"all","blog_pagination_type":"Pagination","flex_smoothHeight":"false"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/includes/lib/assets/min/js/general/fusion-blog.js?ver=1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/includes/lib/assets/min/js/general/fusion-button.js?ver=1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/includes/lib/assets/min/js/general/fusion-general-global.js?ver=1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var fusionIe1011Vars = {"form_bg_color":"#ffffff"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/includes/lib/assets/min/js/general/fusion-ie1011.js?ver=1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var avadaHeaderVars = {"header_position":"top","header_layout":"v1","header_sticky":"1","header_sticky_type2_layout":"menu_only","side_header_break_point":"800","header_sticky_mobile":"0","header_sticky_tablet":"0","mobile_menu_design":"modern","sticky_header_shrinkage":"1","nav_height":"102","nav_highlight_border":"0","nav_highlight_style":"bar","logo_margin_top":"31px","logo_margin_bottom":"31px","layout_mode":"wide","header_padding_top":"0px","header_padding_bottom":"0px","offset_scroll":"full"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/assets/min/js/general/avada-header.js?ver=5.7.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var avadaMenuVars = {"header_position":"Top","logo_alignment":"Left","header_sticky":"1","side_header_break_point":"800","mobile_menu_design":"modern","dropdown_goto":"Go to...","mobile_nav_cart":"Shopping Cart","mobile_submenu_open":"Open Sub Menu","mobile_submenu_close":"Close Sub Menu","submenu_slideout":"1"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/assets/min/js/general/avada-menu.js?ver=5.7.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var fusionScrollToAnchorVars = {"content_break_point":"800","container_hundred_percent_height_mobile":"0"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/includes/lib/assets/min/js/general/fusion-scroll-to-anchor.js?ver=1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var fusionTypographyVars = {"site_width":"1170px","typography_responsive":"","typography_sensitivity":"0.6","typography_factor":"1.5","elements":"h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/includes/lib/assets/min/js/general/fusion-responsive-typography.js?ver=1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/assets/min/js/library/bootstrap.scrollspy.js?ver=3.3.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var avadaCommentVars = {"title_style_type":"double solid","title_margin_top":"0px","title_margin_bottom":"31px"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/assets/min/js/general/avada-comments.js?ver=5.7.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/assets/min/js/general/avada-general-footer.js?ver=5.7.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/assets/min/js/general/avada-quantity.js?ver=5.7.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/assets/min/js/general/avada-scrollspy.js?ver=5.7.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/assets/min/js/general/avada-select.js?ver=5.7.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var avadaSidebarsVars = {"header_position":"top","header_layout":"v1","header_sticky":"1","header_sticky_type2_layout":"menu_only","side_header_break_point":"800","header_sticky_tablet":"0","sticky_header_shrinkage":"1","nav_height":"102","content_break_point":"800"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/assets/min/js/general/avada-sidebars.js?ver=5.7.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/assets/min/js/library/jquery.sticky-kit.js?ver=5.7.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/assets/min/js/general/avada-tabs-widget.js?ver=5.7.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var toTopscreenReaderText = {"label":"Go to Top"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/assets/min/js/library/jquery.toTop.js?ver=1.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var avadaToTopVars = {"status_totop_mobile":"0"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/assets/min/js/general/avada-to-top.js?ver=5.7.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/assets/min/js/general/avada-drop-down.js?ver=5.7.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/assets/min/js/general/avada-contact-form-7.js?ver=5.7.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/assets/min/js/library/jquery.elasticslider.js?ver=5.7.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var avadaElasticSliderVars = {"tfes_autoplay":"1","tfes_animation":"sides","tfes_interval":"3000","tfes_speed":"800","tfes_width":"150"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spin/assets/min/js/general/avada-elastic-slider.js?ver=5.7.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var avadaFusionSliderVars = {"side_header_break_point":"800","slider_position":"below","header_transparency":"1","mobile_header_transparency":"0","header_position":"Top","content_break_point":"800","status_vimeo":"1"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/spinplugins/fusion-core/js/min/avada-fusion-slider.js?ver=1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/inc/js/wp-embed.min.js?ver=5.0.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' defer src='http://example.com/spinplugins/strong-testimonials/public/js/lib/actual/jquery.actual.min.js?ver=1.0.16'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/inc/js/imagesloaded.min.js?ver=3.2.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/inc/js/underscore.min.js?ver=1.8.3'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' defer src='http://example.com/spinplugins/strong-testimonials/public/js/lib/verge/verge.min.js?ver=1.10.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var strong_slider_id_1 = {"config":{"mode":"fade","speed":1000,"pause":8000,"autoHover":1,"autoStart":1,"stopAutoOnClick":1,"adaptiveHeight":0,"adaptiveHeightSpeed":500,"controls":1,"autoControls":0,"pager":0,"slideCount":2,"debug":false,"compat":{"lazyload":{"active":false,"classes":[]}},"touchEnabled":true,"type":"show_single","breakpoints":{"single":{"maxSlides":1,"moveSlides":1,"slideMargin":1},"multiple":{"desktop":{"width":1200,"maxSlides":2,"moveSlides":1,"slideMargin":20},"large":{"width":1024,"maxSlides":2,"moveSlides":1,"slideMargin":20},"medium":{"width":640,"maxSlides":1,"moveSlides":1,"slideMargin":10},"small":{"width":480,"maxSlides":1,"moveSlides":1,"slideMargin":1}}},"stretch":0,"prevText":"","nextText":"","startText":"","stopText":""}};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' defer src='http://example.com/spinplugins/strong-testimonials/public/js/lib/strongslider/jquery.strongslider.min.js?ver=2.32.3'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var strongControllerParms = {"initializeOn":"documentReady","method":"","universalTimer":"500","observerTimer":"500","event":"","script":"","containerId":"page","addedNodeId":"content","debug":""};
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

Comment: This is what comes with using premade themes. You either build your own, non-bloated theme(s), or you remove unused features/scripts/stylesheets by hand - as you're already doing now. There's no other way around it.

Comment: Agree with @cabrerahector, don't see any other way to go with this ...

Answer (score 4):

The theme provides a class that will allow you to manually deregister scripts in a child theme or custom plugin.  Here is an example that would eliminate all :

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_disable_theme_js' );

function custom_disable_theme_js() {
    Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('fusion-chartjs');          
}
```

The theme loads in over a hundred individual scripts, and some may be required for functionality on your site where others will not be, so I found the best approach was to screen out all of the scripts and then add them back in selectively as needed.  With this approach I was able to eliminate 100 JS calls and 1.2MB of unnecessary load in the case where I implemented this approach.

Here's a full list from my initial screen:

```
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('avada-comments');
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('avada-general-footer');
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('avada-mobile-image-hover');
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('avada-quantity');
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('avada-scrollspy');
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('avada-select');
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('avada-sidebars');
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('avada-tabs-widget');

Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('bootstrap-collapse');
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('bootstrap-modal');
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('bootstrap-popover');
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('bootstrap-scrollspy');
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('bootstrap-tab');
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('bootstrap-tooltip');
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('bootstrap-transition');

Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('cssua');

Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('fusion-alert');
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('fusion-blog'); 
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('fusion-button'); 
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('fusion-carousel');
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('fusion-chartjs');
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('fusion-column-bg-image');
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('fusion-count-down');
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('fusion-equal-heights');
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('fusion-flexslider');
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('fusion-image-before-after');
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('fusion-lightbox');
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('fusion-parallax'); 
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('fusion-popover');
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('fusion-recent-posts');
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('fusion-sharing-box');
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('fusion-syntax-highlighter');
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('fusion-testimonials');
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('fusion-title');
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('fusion-tooltip');
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('fusion-video-bg');
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('fusion-video-general');
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('fusion-waypoints');

Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('images-loaded'); 
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('isotope'); 

Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('jquery-appear');
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('jquery-caroufredsel');
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('jquery-count-down');
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('jquery-count-to');
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('jquery-cycle');   
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('jquery-easing');
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('jquery-easy-pie-chart');
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('jquery-event-move');
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('jquery-fade'); 
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('jquery-flexslider');
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('jquery-fitvids');
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('jquery-fusion-maps');
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('jquery-hover-flow');
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('jquery-hover-intent');
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('jquery-infinite-scroll'); 
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('jquery-lightbox');
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('jquery-mousewheel'); 
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('jquery-placeholder');
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('jquery-request-animation-frame');
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('jquery-sticky-kit');
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('jquery-to-top');
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('jquery-touch-swipe'); 
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('jquery-waypoints'); 

Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('lazysizes');
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('modernizr');
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('packery'); 
Fusion_Dynamic_JS::deregister_script('vimeo-player');
```

The theme gets updated from time to time, so this list will likely change.  You can grep for the name of the JS file that you want to deregister in the main theme folder to find out what its handle is.

Answer (score 2):

You can uncheck a lot of scripts by going to Avada Fusion Builder Settings.

Answer (score 0):

Last versión have a optimization wizard, that allows you to detect unused css, custom types and builder features, which helps you to uncheck them and not include their css and javascript in the final package.